# React - бесконечный render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В componentDidUpdate делаю второй поход за данными, что бы после добавления новой задачи( компонент AddTaskInput), изменения статуса или удаления (компонент Task), что бы ре-рендерить TaskList, но рендер происходит сразу же и  получается зацикливание. Проверку в componentDidUpdate делал [по примеру](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).
Как избежать зацикливания?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Task } from './Task'
import { AddTaskInput } from './AddTaskInput.jsx'

export class TaskList extends  React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log("constructor")
    this.state = {
      tasks:null,
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  getTodos() {
    fetch('api/tasks')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(tasks => this.setState({  
        tasks,
        isLoading: false,
      }));
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos()
    console.log('DidMount')
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevState){
    if(prevState.tasks !== this.state.tasks){
      this.getTodos()
    }
  }


  render() {
    console.log("render")
    return this.state.isLoading ? 
      '...Loading...' : (
        <>
          <AddTaskInput/>
          <div className="listWrapper">
            <ul className="taskList">
              <Task
                tasks = {this.state.tasks}
              />
            </ul>
          </div>
        </>
      ) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сравнить два массива

```
prevState.tasks !== this.state.tasks
```

так в js не работает и выражение всегда будет истинно, т.е. вы бесконечно будете вызывать `getTodos()`, который в свою очередь меняет стейт, что опять приводит к вызову `componentDidUpdate`.

Вместо `componentDidUpdate` лучше сделайте отдельные методы для добавления задачи и для удаления задачи, в которых после необходимых действий будете вызывать `getTodos()`